# Deployment Trouble. How can I fix the error returned by "node provisionComposer.js"?

Tags: azure

I have managed to use the composer to build my first chatbot, and it works well with the local emulator.
However, trouble began to pop up when I tried to publish to the AZURE.

I followed the standard deployment procedure published by MIcrosoft.
Specifically, the following script failed and returned the error stating "user not found".

node provisionComposer.js --subscriptionId= --name= --appPassword= --environment=

This node provisionComposer.js returned the following error repeatedly, even after I re-installed node.js:

> using tenant id:  
> creating App registration
> user was not found
> -- Provision Failed --

I checked several times and couldn't figure out why it failed.
I did make sure that I put in the correct "subscription id".
Can anyone shed some light?

Also, I heard I can log in to the Azure portal to create the resource there, and download the corresponding publish configuration JSON from the portal directly (as opposed to the copy it from the cmd console). Can anyone show me an example? Specifically, where on the portal dashboard I can initiate the download to get a local copy of the JSON ffile?

I am new to node.js and AZURE.

Appreciate your help.